# Passing argument from view to Custom RelatedField serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

How can I pass an argument to a serializers.RelatedField class from views.py. I need to pass language_id to query Language.objects model within that RelatedField.

I am not sure if I took a right approach to this issue. What I want to achieve is to present information about genres associated to a movie from database model about depending on the language. The MovieGenre model has genre ID field which I want to replace with actual Genre name.

My serialiser.py

```
class GenreField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value, language_id=1):
        genre_name = GenresVideo.objects.get(genre_id=value, language_id=language_id)
        return genre_name.name

class MovieGenresSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genre_id = GenreField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MoviesGenres
```

As you see, here I query Language.objects with default value but I would like to pass it from views (language_id).

My views.py:

```
class MovieGenresTestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'movie'
    queryset = MoviesGenres.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieGenresSerializer

    def list(self, request, language_pk):
        queryset = MoviesGenres.objects.all()
        serializer = MovieGenresSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, movie, language_pk):
        queryset = MoviesGenres.objects.filter(movie=movie)
        serializer = MovieGenresSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And my urls.py:

```
router.register(r'lang', LanguagesViewSet, base_name='lang')
mov_gen = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'lang', lookup='language')
mov_gen.register(r'mg', MovieGenresTestViewSet, base_name='mg')
url(r'^api/', include(genre_spec.urls))
```

My models.py

```
class Languages(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    short_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default="")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'languages'
        ordering = ('id',)

class GenresVideo(models.Model):
    genre_id = models.IntegerField()
    language = models.ForeignKey('Languages')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'genres_video'
        unique_together = (('genre_id', 'language'),)
        ordering = ('genre_id',)

class MoviesGenres(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movies)
    genre_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'movies_genres'
        unique_together = (('movie', 'genre_id'),)
```

Through the urls routes, I can get a correct response from API including the language_id. I just need to pass it to the view somehow.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: I'm not sure that you've set up the routes correctly. How are your two related models: genre and language ? can you share their description ?

Comment: I've added relevant part of the models.py in original post. Routes are working as I expect them to, so when I send a query like this: /api/lang/1/mg/33/ I do get a correct list of Genres on correct language for that specific movie. For easiness of reading, I have posted only what I though to be relevant in this case, but I might have missed some crucial parts as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer to your first question, with the easiest implementation possible: [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). Because we will get the language id via the context passed to the serializer, we should either generate the context for the serializer, or let the framework do that for us.

Now to the problem at hand: you aren't filtering the queryset (MoviesGenres) by language per se. Thus, we can avoid overwriting the list and retrieve methods. Nevertheless, the router mechanism will inject in kwargs for the view method the language_pk parameter - that's the parameter that we will retrieve from within the serializer context:

```python
class MovieGenresSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genre = searializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = MoviesGenres

    def get_genre(self, instance):
        # get the language id from the view kwargs
        language_id = self.context['view'].kwargs['language_pk']
        # get the genre
        try:
            genre_name = GenresVideo.objects.get(genre_id=instance.genre_id, language_id=language_id).name
        except GenresVideo.DoesNotExist:
            genre_name = None
        # return the formatted output
        return genre_name


class MovieGenresTestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'movie'
    queryset = MoviesGenres.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieGenresSerializer
```

Comment: I get KeyError: 'view' from this line: language_id = self.context['view'].kwargs['parent_lookup_language'].

Comment: can you inspect the content of self.context ?

Comment: Never mind that. It looks that your overwrite of list and retrieve are rendering out the preparation of context. I think it's safe now to go with their default implementation. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Now I get KeyError for 'parent_lookup_language'

Comment: Hmm... normally that should be the name of the parent lookup. Can you debug and inspect the keys @ that stage? We need to know what are the available names in kwargs.

Comment: I see you are using drf-nested-routes; I was assuming you are using drf-extensions. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Let me know if the updated answer works out for you.

Comment: It partially does, so when I request /api/lang/3/mg/ I do get a list of all movies and genres with correct language, but when I want to filter per movie (/api/lang/3/mg/22/) by movie ID, it is sending get request but I receive a list (all genres that that specific movie has). If I overwrite list and retrieve in views, I get again Key error for 'view'

Comment: Isn't that correct ? If for one movie (based on which you are filtering) you have more genres, then the result is correct, right? Perhaps you need to install additional filters. Also, in your former implementation, on the retrieve item route, you also return a list (you have the serializer instantiated with many=True).

Comment: I've been giving more thoughts to your design; if I may, a suggestion: language_id is a presentation type of parameter, rather then to designate a specific object. A genre is the same genre in all languages, it's just presenting itself differently (spells differently). Based on this observation and the good recommendation of url composition, parameters which have to do with presentation of the objects should go into the query parameters rather then in the clear url. To your specific case: language_id should stay in the query params and be retrieved with a default value. Makes sense?

Comment: By all means, all suggestions are very welcome, and thanks a lot for all your help so far. Regarding the first comment, yes, I do get multiple times as a result but since we are using default retrieve I get error MultipleObjectsReturned while expecting single one. If I overwrite method, then context returns empty dict. (by the way, where can I find more info on context?).

Regarding second comment, I already tried with query parameters and filters but I was not successful at times but I will try again and let you know. Thanks again for your efforts, I learned a lot.

Comment: The serializer context comes from here: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L131; Whenever you overwrite the basic methods of the ViewSet, the context isn't generated anymore. In fact, alot isn't done anymore: filtering, pagination, serializer creation.

Comment: I think there's a fault in the design of the viewset: if a movie has several genres, then that's what you should return, on a list route rather than on a detail route.

Comment: Well, I do, but problems is that I need to replace genre_id with correct language string for front end. And I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Can I pass many=True to views without overwriting the methods or can I include context when I overwrite them?

Comment: Glad to hear that! Good luck!